# On decreasing the variance of estimators given additional information.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X,Y$ be two random variables with parametric probability densities respectively $p_X(x, \sigma_X)$ and $ p_Y(y, \sigma_Y)$ where $\sigma_X , \sigma_Y \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy an equation of the type $f(\sigma_x) = \sigma_y$ for some function $f$. In the following, For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that $\sigma_x = 2 \sigma_y$.

Suppose that given an observation $X_1,Y_1$ of each random variable  one wishes to obtain the best (in the least variance sense) estimators possible $\hat{\sigma}_x, \hat{\sigma}_y$ for $\sigma_x, \sigma_y$.

Without knowing that the true parameters satisfy the equation $\sigma_x = 2 \sigma_y$ I  would take the estimators as
$$ \hat{\sigma}_x =  \max_\sigma p_X (X_1, \sigma), \quad  \hat{\sigma}_y =  \max_\sigma p_Y (Y_1, \sigma) $$
the standard maximum likelihood estimators (the variance will be high since we have only one observation but this is another matter).

If one also knew that the equation $\sigma_x = 2\sigma_y$ holds it seems reasonable to expect that one could improve the estimator **taking into consideration this additional information**, in the sense that I would expect to find  two estimators $\tilde{\sigma}_x, \tilde{\sigma}_y$ such that 
$$Var[\tilde{\sigma}_x] < Var[ \hat{\sigma}_x], \quad Var[\tilde{\sigma}_y] < Var [\hat{\sigma}_y]$$

How would one go about doing this? If this is a standard problem in statistics references are very welcome.

NB: I am aware that the maximum likelihood estimators are not always the most efficient estimators, they are cited here as an example to motivate the question.

Comment: Do you know the joint density of $X,Y$ ? If yes, $max_{\sigma}p_{X,Y}(x,y,\sigma)$...

Comment: @Bertrand  can you recover the joint density from the fact that $\sigma_x = 2 \sigma_y$ ?  Also this would give me a single estimator.

Comment: @Monilite: No, the information you give does not allow me to obtain the expression of the joint density.